# An equilateral triangle whose vertices are Fermat points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Can you prove the following claim:

> **Claim.** Given an arbitrary $\triangle ABC$. The isosceles $\triangle ADB$ , $\triangle BEC$ and $\triangle CFA$ are constructed on the sides of the $\triangle ABC$ externally . Let $F_1$,$F_2$,$F_3$ be the Fermat points of the  $\triangle ADB$ , $\triangle BEC$ , $\triangle CFA$ , respectively. Then the  $\triangle F_1F_2F_3$ is an equilateral triangle.

[image]

GeoGebra applet that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/vr2mw5ct).

Using a little bit of trigonometry one can show that the Fermat point lies at an angle of exactly $30^{\circ}$ relative to the base for all isosceles triangles , which means that $\angle 
 BAF_1=\angle F_1BA=\angle CBF_2=\angle F_2CB=\angle ACF_3=\angle F_3AC = 30^{\circ}$ . I am stuck here. I don't know how to proceed with the proof.  Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: You've reduced the result to [Napoleon's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon%27s_theorem), since the Fermat points of the isosceles triangles are centers of equilateral ones.

Comment: The channel Think Twice has a really elegant solution of this problem. Check this :https://youtu.be/KQ8cSuoopyc